# Preventing unncessary cursor after maxlength complete on input

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" style="letter-spacing: 0.9em;">
```

[image]

We can put the cursor from our mouse to fourth position. How can we prevent this?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vusan/6qfc1qw4/)

Comment: how do you want to prevent this? Explain what is the expected behavior

Comment: Blur the focus on input field?

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; using this line of code, I can not reproduce the problem in Chrome.

Comment: Change focus to another text box once maxlength criteria is met. You will have to write `js` for this though.

Comment: @cBroe input has letter spacing on css

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala I had already tried it. `this.value.length == maxLength`. but cursor can be placed by selecting with mouse, etc.

Comment: _“Here even the maxlength is completed, cursor moved to fourth position.”_ - that is not actually what happens. Mark/select a single of those “1” with your mouse, and you will see that you effectively have increased the “width” of a single character by adding letter-spacing. The cursor _is_ behind the third character, there is no actual “fourth position”, it just looks that way ...

Comment: @ElmerDantas I had put boxes on background for one character. But due to unnecessary cursor, number gets misplaced from the box(actual width is just fit with the three character.

Comment: @CBroe look my above comment.

Comment: preventing cursor with `blur` and `focus` should solve this for you but it seems that css is also a problem in your case. I suggest you create a fiddle with your actual css/html to reproduce what you have and what you want to avoid...

Comment: @ElmerDantas I updated with fiddle with Shalitha's solution as well. But the problem was cursor to fourth position due to mouse.

Comment: Shalita's solution works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6qfc1qw4/1/ . At least on Chrome.

Comment: No it will not allow to edit textbox then when maxlength completed.

Comment: what do you think about this? https://jsfiddle.net/6qfc1qw4/2/

Comment: `But due to unnecessary cursor, number gets misplaced from the box(actual width is just fit with the three character.` - is this specific to any browser? When I checked the fiddle in Chrome I don't see any such behavior.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Hey my problem was only that the number gets misplaced from the box like this https://jsfiddle.net/6qfc1qw4/4/. check this one https://jsfiddle.net/6qfc1qw4/3/

Comment: @VivekAthalye My fiddle on the question has width which can handle 4 character. I mean this one https://jsfiddle.net/6qfc1qw4/4/ this box can handle only three characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `blur()` to focus out

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="3" onkeyup="if(this.value.length == 3) this.blur()">
```

**Update**

Also you can disable when you click or select using keyboard too using `onfocus()`

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="3" onkeyup="if(this.value.length == 3) this.blur()" onfocus="if(this.value.length == 3) this.blur()">
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It will not help me because we can place cursor from mouse.

Comment: @vusan Then blur it again with js... It's not that hard. Use an event click listener and then apply the blur on it.

Comment: I put boxes on background which actually fit only three character. But by using mouse the character gets misplaced with box. I had already tried with auto tab change with maxlength completed.